Order within each product
I  want to prioritize the sub_product within each product_id.



Product_id
Sub_product
Category




10101010
02020202
Superior


10101010
02020204
High-valued


0120202
0930303
High-valued


0120202
039303
VALUE


0303303
039302929
VALUE


0303303
0393342929
AddOn



Here is the expected results:



Product_id
Sub_product
Category
Priority




10101010
02020202
Superior
1


10101010
02020204
High-valued
2


0120202
0930303
High-valued
1


0120202
039303
VALUE
2


0303303
039302929
VALUE
1


0303303
0393342929
AddOn
2



Order of priority:
Superior = 1
High-valued = 2
VALUE = 3
AddOn = 4

Using derived column, I can achieve the below output.



Product_id
Sub_product
Category
Priority




10101010
02020202
Superior
1


10101010
02020204
High-valued
2


0120202
0930303
High-valued
2


0120202
039303
VALUE
3


0303303
039302929
VALUE
3


0303303
0393342929
AddOn
4



Is it possible to start the number from 1 for each product_id?

After derived column, you can use window transformation and group it over product_id column and apply rank() function for each group. Below are the steps in dataflow.

Give the Product_id column name in the over section of window settings.



Give the Priority column that is computed from derived column transformation step in sort section of window settings.



In Windows columns, give the column name Priority_new  and expression as rank().



Below is the output data.


